# MySQL large table - querying is very slow

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table, `AdsPOI`, which has the following structure:

```
 AdsPOIId  (bigint 20) PRIMARY, AUTO INCREMENT
 Distance  (int 6) not indexed
 poi_POIId (bigint 20) INDEXED, references another table POI
 ads_AdId  (bigint 20) INDEXED, references another table Ads
```

In this table, currently there are ~7.000.000 rows, but it is growing every minute, larger and larger. The table is an `InnoDB` table. Even when I try to make the simplest query to the table, for example: `SELECT * FROM AdsPOI ORDER BY ads_AdId`, the query takes around 20 seconds to run. When I try a more complex query, like `SELECT poi_POIId FROM AdsPOI WHERE ads_AdId > 5 AND ads_AdId < 300000 GROUP BY poi_POIId` the query takes around 1 minute and 20 seconds, and returns around ~130.000 rows.

Is there any way to fasten these queries? Is it normal, that these queries run so slow? How could I try to make them faster?

Comment: You know that InnoDB is configured by default to use 8MB of RAM? If it can't use RAM to store its working dataset there, it's going to use disk for seeking. That's what's slow, finding the data. Look for the value of this config variable: `innodb_buffer_pool_size` and increase it (it's in your `.cnf` file, but you can query for the value using `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer_pool%';`).

Comment: the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is 134217728. Is this value in bytes? That means, it is 128MB. I try to increase it.

Comment: Yes, it's in bytes. Usually, for database servers, I personally use between 80% and 90% of available RAM (however, we're running servers with 32gb of RAM or more). The more you can allocate for InnoDB, the better. That way it avoids disk I/O and finding the data becomes faster.

Comment: Your second query is nonsensical. One tip for optimization is to name the columns you actually want returned.

Comment: @Strawberry, why is it nonsensical? `poi_POIId` is not unique. I mean, multiple `ads_AdId` can have the same `poi_POIId`

Comment: OK, it's not nonsensical - and irritatingly, there is a performance benefit associated with using GROUP BY instead of DISTINCT. But, as a rule, GROUP BY is for use with aggregating functions, and DISTINCT is for all other cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to optimize your disk I/O by increasing the innodb_buffer_pool_size and therefore moving recently accessed tables into the RAM.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-diskio.html

Answer (score -2):

You can only do so much with a relational database and vast amounts of data. If you already have millions of entries in a properly indexed table, and it's growing fast, you can expect queries to be getting even slower. Adding more powerful hardware is an option.

A big data NoSQL tool optimized for huge amounts of data, like MongoDB, could be a better design choice if you can live without the foreign keys relations.

Comment: You're completely wrong. You think that NoSQL has some magic algorithm that lets it use computer resources better and that people developing relational databases are dumb and never thought of them?